# How start a default message and gmail apps in separate buttons onclick method?

Tags: android

emailBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager()
                    .getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.gms");
            startActivity(LaunchIntent);

        }
    });
```

smsBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent LaunchIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            LaunchIntent.setData(Uri.parse(" sms:"));
            startActivity(LaunchIntent);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

for sending sms

```
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "default content");
                sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
                startActivity(sendIntent);
```

or

```
    Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager()
                        .getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.mms");
                startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

add permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

use this two lines in  smsBtn click events

for sending mails

just change pacage name in emailBtn click event 
to `com.google.android.gm`

Comment: Than u for you'r response, email part is good but  i don't want to send message to default number, just open the app when click the buuton

Comment: Just want click the button to open the message app

Comment: Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager()
      .getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.sms");
    startActivity(LaunchIntent);

Comment: no that comment give only a permission but i want open that message application when click the button like email part

Comment: which sms application?

Comment: default device message app

Comment: this will open your device default app  and check my edit for solution

Comment: fine but where it's to be used

Comment: means ? what you want to achieve ??

Comment: we create a app then a particular activity has need a device default sms   app when click a button in our app

Comment: nothing but email part....i think my package name is fault but i could not get that

Comment: command prompt cannot be allowed more characters, so plz send ur mail id or can i post another question in this website

Comment: well do not do this just write it in github and give me that link

Comment: no it's need lot of suggestions so i cant do that, i have already send my code in above, just click the button(my app) and open the message app like email part

Comment: i cant understand please write full description. and "com.android.mms" its package name  of default message app so try it and if you are getting an error then post your logcat output here  and now do not discuss here. edit your question with full description

Comment: how to open the gmail part in your suggestion, thats the way i want open sms part also

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22985122/how-to-open-default-message-app-in-my-android-application

Comment: well check package name what i have write and what you wrote.

Comment: its permission and i am talking about ".getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.mms");"

Comment: k fine i already found that but, i think MMS used for multimedia message So, thats the reason for i got confused